# Inverse of the tangent map for tangent bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-bundle

(Physicist here trying to understand some more involved differential geometry).
In the context of differential geometry we define the tangent bundle as

$ TM = \bigsqcup_{p \in M} T_p(M) $ where a general element is given by the cartesian product $(p,v_P)$ for $p \in M$ and $v_p \in T_p(M)$.

We have the natural map $\pi: TM \rightarrow M$, explicitly $\pi(p,v_p)=p$, called the tangent map.

However, we then define the inverse tangent map as $\pi^{-1}: M \rightarrow TM$ but I dont understand how we can do this. The tangent map is surjective and so its inverse does not uniquely map onto an element in the tangent bundle.

Comment: You are correct. $\pi^{-1}$ as inverse to $\pi$ does not make sense. Without further context, I don't have a clue what was actually meant, though.

Comment: More context would definitely be helpful. For any map $f : X \to Y$ and $y \in Y$ we sometimes denote $f^{-1}(y) := \{x \in X : f(x) = y\}$---this is the **preimage of $y$ under $f$**. For a point $p \in M$, $\pi^{-1}(p)$ is the **fiber** $T_p M$ of $TM$ over $p$.

Comment: Let me emphasize that @Travis is undoubtedly giving the right response to this question. Statements of local triviality will have the notation $\pi^{-1}(U) \cong U\times \Bbb R^k$, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Thorgott said we cannot have a true inverse function from $M$ to $TM$ because $\pi : TM \to M$ is not injective.

However, vector fields $X$ (i.e. [sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(fiber_bundle)) of $TM$) are a "half inverse" to $\pi$ in the sense that they give you a map from $M$ back up to $TM$. Specifically, for each $p \in M$ the vector field $X$ gives a vector $X_p \in T_pM \subset TM$. Formally, vector fields satisfy the equation $\pi \circ X = \text{id}_M$, so they are right inverses to $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Would X here then define a 'section of the fiber bundle'? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_%28fiber_bundle%29

Comment: Yes, that’s right. The tangent bundle is an example of a vector bundle, which is a special case of fiber bundle where the fibers attached to each point of the base space are vector spaces.